# How to fill my .xml file from URL?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, inputstream

I'm building a weather application where I need to fill an *.xml* file with data from an *URL*.

The URL for the *XML* file is *http://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml*, and I have created a file named *NewFile.xml*.

When I download this URL data manualy and import it into *Eclipse IDE*, it works fine. But is such a way, I can't have the las content of the remote resource.

Below is the code part I'm using:

```java
String readXML = null;
URL url = null;
URLConnection urlconn = null;

try {
    url = new URL("http://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml");
    urlconn = url.openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    InputStreamReader inst = new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(inst);
    boolean eof = false;
    while (!eof) {
        readXML = bfr.readLine();
        if (readXML == null) {
            eof = true;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("NewFile.xml");
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fout, "UTF8");
    out.write(readXML);
} catch (IOException z) {
    System.out.println("Nešto se sjebalo.");
}

try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("NewFile.xml");                                            //Dokument

    NodeList cityList = doc.getElementsByTagName("GradIme");
    Node cNode = cityList.item(12);

    if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element cElement = (Element) cNode;
        String city = cElement.getTextContent();
        System.out.println("Ime grada: " + city);
    }

    NodeList tempList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Temp");                                //Element po nazivu
    Node nNode = tempList.item(12);                                                        //Item number

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {                                        // provjeta tipa podataka == Element

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;                                            // Element nNode
        String temperatura = eElement.getTextContent();                                    //uzima text iz elementa
        System.out.println("Temperatura:" + temperatura + " C");

        NodeList vlagaList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Vlaga");
        Node vNode = vlagaList.item(12);

        if (vNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element vElement = (Element) vNode;
            String vlaga = vElement.getTextContent();
            System.out.println("Vlaga u zraku: " + vlaga + "%");
        }
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? You get error? Or have unexpected result?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
 at VrijemeDanas.main(VrijemeDanas.java:68)

Comment: This is what I get. Its a line with OutputStream, when I try to write data into NewFile.xml

Comment: Please add the exception stack to the main post.

Comment: It happens because `readXML` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage to cleanup your `main` method: You are almost separating code blocks for file reading and writing which results in `readXml` input being `null` when you are trying to write it to target file.

Here down a slightly modified version of you source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String readXML;
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlconn;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml");
        urlconn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bfr = null;
        InputStreamReader inst = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        Writer out = null;
        try { // read & write in the same block
            inst = new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream());
            bfr = new BufferedReader(inst);
            fout = new FileOutputStream("NewFile.xml");
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(fout, "UTF8");
            while ((readXML = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(readXML);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { // cleanup your resources
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (fout != null) {
                fout.close();
            }
            if (bfr != null) {
                bfr.close();
            }
            if (inst != null) {
                inst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("NewFile.xml");                                            //Dokument

        NodeList cityList = doc.getElementsByTagName("GradIme");
        Node cNode = cityList.item(12);

        if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element cElement = (Element) cNode;
            String city = cElement.getTextContent();
            System.out.println("Ime grada: " + city);
        }

        NodeList tempList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Temp");                                //Element po nazivu
        Node nNode = tempList.item(12);                                                        //Item number

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {                                        // provjeta tipa podataka == Element

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;                                            // Element nNode
            String temperatura = eElement.getTextContent();                                    //uzima text iz elementa
            System.out.println("Temperatura:" + temperatura + " C");

            NodeList vlagaList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Vlaga");
            Node vNode = vlagaList.item(12);

            if (vNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element vElement = (Element) vNode;
                String vlaga = vElement.getTextContent();
                System.out.println("Vlaga u zraku: " + vlaga + "%");
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should note that this should be an experimental code snippet and you should manage to cleanup more if you need a production-ready code.
Pay particular attention to resources cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, it's using [Java 8 nio API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).

```
public void downloadFile(final String url, final String targetPath) throws IOException {

    final URL website = new URL(url);
    final Path target = Paths.get(targetPath);
    System.out.println(target.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    try (InputStream in = website.openStream()) {
        Files.copy(in, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}

//You can call the function
downloadFile("http://vrijeme.hr/hrvatska_n.xml", "NewFile.xml");
```